# i am getting the error "warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]"

Tags: c, gcc, gtk, gnu

i am getting the error because for gtk_entry it takes char type as input but i want to give it int type so first i declared int type then this int type is declared to char type and given to gtk_entry but i am getting error.

```
#include<gtk/gtk.h>


void static call(GtkWidget *widget,gpointer data)
{
g_print("\n%s\n",gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(data)));
gint answ=4;
const char* ans=answ; //here is the line having error
gtk_entry_set_text(GTK_ENTRY(data),ans);
gtk_editable_select_region(GTK_EDITABLE(data),0,-1);

}

int main(int agrc, char *agrv[])

{
gtk_init(&agrc,&agrv);
GtkWidget *entry,*window,*button,*hbox;

window=gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
g_signal_connect(window,"delete-event",G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit),NULL);

hbox=gtk_hbox_new(0,0);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window),hbox);
button=gtk_button_new_with_mnemonic("write text");
entry=gtk_entry_new();
g_signal_connect(button,"clicked",G_CALLBACK(call),entry);
g_signal_connect(entry,"activate",G_CALLBACK(call),entry);



gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox),button,0,0,0);

gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox),entry,0,0,0);

gtk_widget_show_all(window);
gtk_main();
return 0;

}
```

Comment: what exactly is the line that gives you the error?

Comment: `const char* ans=answ;`

Comment: Again, why do you want to assign the integer 4 to a char? Or is it the char '4' what you want to assing?

Comment: i want to assign integer to gtk_entry but integer cannot be assigned so im am trying to assign 4 as char to gtk_entry

Comment: @fernando.reyes first i have declared x=4 as integer then y=x is declared as char because char can be assigned to gtk_entry not integer.

Comment: The problem is exactly how you describe it, the function takes a char as argument, so, if you want to give it the number 4 you have to make char* ans = '4'; otherwise the compiler will keep whining

Comment: @fernando.reyes is there any way to assign 4 as integer to gtk_entry?? i have to assign integer value to gtk_entry. suppose i add two number and the result is then assigned to gtk_entry. how i can to it because addition of two number will always be an integer

Comment: the function needs a char as parameter, so, what you want is '4' as a char, you can't and don't want to pass a 4 as parameter. I'm adding you an answer to what you're asking

Comment: You just want to put the text `"4"` in place. Why don't you just do that? `gtk_entry_set_text(GTK_ENTRY(data), "4");` You should read up about strings in C, `char` arrays and stuff like that. You find that anywhere on the web.

Comment: @fernando.reyes suppose i add two number and then i have display the result in gtk_entry. addition of two numbers will always be an integer. so how i can display the result in gtk_entry????

Comment: @JensGustedt suppose i add two numbers and then i have to display the result in gtk_entry. addition of two numbers will always be an integer. so how i can display the result in gtk_entry???? do i have to convert that integer in character then display it ??

Comment: @user3132152 Your API requires a `const char*` Blindly assigning an variable of an unrelated and (as clearly shown by your warning) non-standard convertible type isn't the way to do that. Jens' comment is correct. You likely need more time on the fundamentals of C string management, and add to that type conversions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to convert an integer to char so you can pass such integer as parameter, you will do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main(void)
    {
       char c[4];
       int i=5;
       sprintf(c, "%d", i);
       printf("%s %d", c, i);
       return 0;
    }
```

You use sprintf to print your integer into a char variable, and then use it. There is a function itoa that is not standard but will help you too.

itoa is used like:

```
itoa(c, i, 10);
```

edit:

Your code I think working is:

```
gint x=4; 
char y[4]; 
sprintf(y, "%d", x);
gtk_entry_set_text(GTK_ENTRY(data),y);
```

Comment: `gint x=4;`
 `const char* y;`
 `itoa(x,y,10);`
       `gtk_entry_set_text(GTK_ENTRY(data),y);`                                i have tried this but now i am getting another error `(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to itoa
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: You can try the correction I posted above, or try adding #include<stdlib.h> that is the library necessary for itoa

Comment: thanks :) . its working now . i want to know one more thing why `char y[4]` is used instead of `char y` . i am new to C so it might be a stupid question but i want to learn things

Comment: You need memory where you will save the data. When you declare char *y; you create a pointer to nothing, either you need to take some memory with char *y = malloc(4, sizeof(char)); or you declare it with some size like char y[4]. The size should be enough for the string you plan to put in there and the null char in the end of the string, hence y[4] has enough space for '0' to '999'.

Comment: please vote up my question i cannot ask questions i am banned. thanks